# 4096 vs 12! Binary Combinatorics in 12 bits

Tags: combinatorics

Given a $3\times4$ matrix keypad, each key encoded onto a unique index on a 12 bit string (0000-0000-0000), the maximum combinations are $2^{12}=4096$.

However, $12$ available keys have a maximum possible combination of $12!$.

Obviously, it's pretty hard to map $12!$ values into a space of $4096$ possible combinations.

What am I missing here? I've been trying to figure it out for an hour.

Comment: You are missing that a permutation of a 12 bits string may be the string itself.

Comment: You're... counting different things! You're not even mapping $12!$ values into this space. What does your $12!$ even mean? Are you wondering where to put which key on your $3 \times 4$ matrix pad? This has nothing to do with the bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had 12 different symbols to put in 12 slots, you would have $12!$ different ways to do this (assuming each symbol is used once).  However you are putting $0$s and $1$s into the slots--two choices per slot for a total of $2^{12}$ ways to do it.

Comment: I forgot, it's only 2 possible per slot as you say, and the slots are in a specific order. In other words, is combinatorics vs permutations, order isn't important because combinations are automatically ordered via the indexes of their components. 12! is when order matters, but on a key pad, if 1 & 2 are hit at the same time, it's one state, regardless of the order.